# Visual Studio C/C++ struct char issue

Tags: c++, .net, c#-4.0, visual-c++

I am trying to interface some C/C++ code from C# via a dll. I am not a fluent C/C++ programmer but use C# all the time. I am attempting to deal with these C/C++ types at the moment:

```
#ifndef struct_emxArray_char_T_1024
#define struct_emxArray_char_T_1024
struct emxArray_char_T_1024
{
    char_T data[1024];
    int32_T size[1];
};

#ifndef typedef_e_struct_T
#define typedef_e_struct_T
typedef struct
{
    emxArray_char_T_1024 value1;
    real_T value2;
    uint32_T value3;
    boolean_T value4;
} e_struct_T;
```

They were created by a third party tool. My unsuccessful C/C++ attempt to initialize value1 is as follows:

```
static char_T test[5] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

emxArray_char_T_1024 x;
x.data = test;
x.size = 5;

e_struct_T Parameters;
Parameters.value1 = x;
Parameters.value2 = 50;
Parameters.value3 = 3;
Parameters.value4 = FALSE;
```

I would like to ultimately expose a C# interface which takes the values:

```
PerformCPlusPlusComputation(string value1, double value2, int value3, bool value)
```

which initializes e_struct_T in C/C++. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines

```
x.data = test;
x.size = 5;
```

contains two errors: The first is that you can't assign one array to another, not even if they were the same size. Use e.g. [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy from one to the other.

The other error is that the `size` member is an array as well, and you can't assign a single value to an array. You have to assign to `x.size[0]`.

---

Correct lines *could* look like this:

```
std::copy(std::begin(test), std::end(test), std::begin(x.data));
x.size[0] = sizeof(test);
```

Comment: Thanks I will have a look into this. If you feel like it could you please provide the correct lines of code?

Comment: Thanks - will try this tomorrow. Sorry for being lazy ... (-:

Comment: Thanks. You forgot a type cast though: x.size[0] = (int32_T) sizeof(test)